# java.time.temporal.ValueRange bug when constructing

Tags: java

I am working with some time stuff in a project, and as I was implementing unit testing, I am not sure if I have found a bug, or if I have have just misunderstood the documentation.  The javadocs for **[`ValueRange.of(long min, long maxSmallest, long maxLargest)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html#of(long,long,long))** state:

```
 * @return the ValueRange for min, smallest max, largest max, not null
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if
 *     the minimum is greater than the smallest maximum,
 *  or the smallest maximum is greater than the largest maximum
```

The way I read that is if the value passed for min is larger than the value for maxSmallest, it should throw an exception.  However, the following code works:

`ValueRange vr = ValueRange.of(5, 2, 10);`

I think this should fail.  The value for min is larger than the value for smallest maximum, but no exception is thrown.  In addition, when printing the resulting ValueRange, it looks very strange:  *5 - 2/10*

Is this a bug?  Or am I just not understanding the javadocs?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. My current source inspector says that it checks for `min > maxLargest`, while javadoc says it should check `min > minLargest`. One of them certainly isn't right.

Comment: Create a bug report at oracle.

Comment: Update: it's the javadoc for `of(long, long, long)` that is wrong. See javadoc for `of(long, long, long, long)`, which says "or the largest minimum is greater than the largest maximum", which is indeed what it checks for. Though I'd consider the one from the "wrong" javadoc more intuitive behavior.

Comment: I cannot find any (documentation for) `java.util.ValueRange`... OK, found it, but in `java.time.temporal`

Comment: it looks like that condition was forgotten in `of(long, long, long, long)` (kind of "smallest minimum greater than smallest maximum")

Comment: Your code ended up in the JDK [bug fix](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/be0c5da2d83f#l2.24)!

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug [JDK-8239520](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239520) and it has been [fixed](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/be0c5da2d83f) in JDK 15 [Build 12](https://jdk.java.net/15/release-notes#b12).

I have created unit tests based on [ValueRange.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html#of(long,long)) API for different value ranges:

```java
package org.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

public class ValueRangeTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
        "5, 2" // the minimum is greater than the maximum
    })
    public void testFixedValueRange(long min, long max) {
        Executable when = () -> ValueRange.of(min, max);

        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, when,
                () -> "min: " + min + ", max: " + max);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
        "5, 2, 10", // the minimum is greater than the smallest maximum - THIS FAILS!
        "2, 10, 2" // the smallest maximum is greater than the largest maximum
    })
    public void testVariableValueRange(long min, long maxSmallest, long maxLargest) {
        Executable when = () -> ValueRange.of(min, maxSmallest, maxLargest);

        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, when,
                () -> "min: " + min + ", maxSmallest: " + maxSmallest + ", maxLargest: " + maxLargest);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
        "5, 1, 2, 10", // the smallest minimum is greater than the smallest maximum
        "1, 2, 10, 2", // the smallest maximum is greater than the largest maximum
        "1, 11, 2, 10" // the largest minimum is greater than the largest maximum
    })
    public void testFullyVariableValueRange(long minSmallest, long minLargest, long maxSmallest, long maxLargest) {
        Executable when = () -> ValueRange.of(minSmallest, minLargest, maxSmallest, maxLargest);

        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, when,
                () -> "minSmallest: " + minSmallest + ", minLargest: " + minLargest + ", maxSmallest: " + maxSmallest + ", maxLargest: " + maxLargest);
    }

}
```

All scenarios pass but one - `if the minimum is greater than the smallest maximum`

```
Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.087 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.mycompany.mavenproject1.ValueRangeTest
testVariableValueRange{long, long, long}[1]  Time elapsed: 0.034 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: min: 5, maxSmallest: 2, maxLargest: 10 ==> Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
    at org.mycompany.mavenproject1.ValueRangeTest.testVariableValueRange(ValueRangeTest.java:30)
```

This makes me believe that this is a bug in the `ValueRange`.